# When to reduce in a shift-reduce parser?

Tags: parsing, bottom-up

This is the skeleton of my bottom-up parser:

```
while (!stack.empty())
{
    if (!reduce())
    {
        shift();
    }
}
```

And I have these rules:

```
Program -> Expr
Expr -> Expr '+' Expr
Expr -> Number
Number -> FLOAT | INTEGER  // These 2 are terminal symbols
```

If I have the following input:

```
2 + 3
```

2 gets pushed onto the stack, then gets reduced to a Number, then an Expression and then a Program. So it doesn't have any chance to parse the whole addition. How can I force the parser to parse the rest too? Should I do something like:

```
Program -> Expr EOF
```

?

Bottom-up parsing is pretty new for me so any help is appreciated.

Comment: BTW: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2626723/859279)'s a similar question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a look-ahead to decide whether to shift or reduce. Your example grammar fits in the LR(1) family of grammars, so a bottomup parser with a 1 symbol look-ahead should be able to capture it.

In your example you have input:

```
2 + 3
```

So you build up a stack:

```
Program, Expr, Number
```

Shift `FLOAT`, reduce `Number`, reduce `Expr`. Now you have a choice, whether to reduce `Program` or shift `'+'`, so you look ahead is there is a `'+'`. If so you shift and follow the `Expr = Expr '+' Expr` rule.

You may still want to do `Program = Expr EOF` so your lookahead can always return `EOF` if there's nothing left to parse.

Comment: How do I decide when to push the lookahead?

Comment: You can calculate [lookahead sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser#Lookahead_sets) from the grammar.